# Value error with array dimensions in bilstm

Tags: keras

I have some data that consists in 1000 samples with 35 features and one class prediction, so it could take only the values 0 or 1. I want to use a stacked bilstm over a cnn and for that reason I would like to tune the hyperparameters. Actually I am having a hard time for making the program to run, here is my code:

```
def bilstmCnn(X,y):
    number_of_features = X.shape[1]
    number_class = 2
    batch_size = 32
    epochs = 300
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X.values, y.values, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
    
    tune(X,y)

def build_model(hp):
    number_of_features = 35
    number_of_classes = 2

    model = Sequential()

    # Convolutional Layer
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=hp.Int('conv_filter', min_value=16, max_value=256, step=16),
                     kernel_size=hp.Int('conv_kernel', min_value=3, max_value=9, step=2),
                     activation='relu', input_shape=(number_of_features, 1)))

    # Reshape Layer
    timesteps = number_of_features // model.layers[0].kernel_size[0]
    model.add(Reshape((timesteps, model.layers[0].filters)))

    # Pooling Layer
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=hp.Int('pool_size', min_value=2, max_value=5, step=1)))

    # Bidirectional LSTM Layer
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(units=hp.Int('lstm_units', min_value=16, max_value=512, step=16),
                                 return_sequences=False)))

    # Dropout Layer
    model.add(Dropout(hp.Float('dropout', 0, 0.5, step=0.1)))

    # Dense Layer
    model.add(Dense(units=hp.Int('dense_units', min_value=16, max_value=512, step=16),
                    activation='relu'))

    # Output Layer
    model.add(Dense(units=number_of_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

    optimizer = hp.Choice('optimizer', values=[Adam(), RMSprop(), SGD()])
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), metrics=[Accuracy()])

def tune2(X, y):
    hp = HyperParameters()

    batch_size = hp.Choice("batch_size", [16, 32, 64, 128, 256])

    tuner = kt.RandomSearch(
        build_model3,
        hyperparameters=hp,
        objective="val_accuracy",
        max_trials=5,
        executions_per_trial=3,
        overwrite=True,
    )

    print(tuner.search_space_summary())

    x_train_val, x_test, y_train_val, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)
    x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train_val, y_train_val, test_size=0.1, random_state=0)

    tuner.search(
        x_train, y_train,
        epochs=300,
        validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=2)],
        verbose=2,
    )

    best_model = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=1)[0]
    best_hyperparameters = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(1)[0]

    print(best_hyperparameters.values)

    test_loss, test_acc = best_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)

    print(f'Test accuracy: {test_acc*100}')
    print(f'Best hyperparameters: {best_hyperparameters.values}')

    y_pred = best_model.predict(x_test)
    y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred > 0.5, axis=1)

    tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred).ravel()

    precision = (tp / (tp + fp)) * 100
    recall = (tp / (tp + fn)) * 100
    specificity = (tn / (tn + fp)) * 100
    f1_score = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)

    print(f'Precision: {precision:.4f}')
    print(f'Recall: {recall:.4f}')
    print(f'Specificity: {specificity:.4f}')
    
    return model
```

but the error that I receive is the following:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [33, 16], output_shape = [11, 16]
```

I have tried to modify with no luck at all. What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Meh, what is the point of reshaping in this model? **Just delete them**:

```
timesteps = number_of_features // model.layers[0].kernel_size[0]
model.add(Reshape((timesteps, model.layers[0].filters)))
```

You don't need them and you can't reshape to that shape. It doesn't make any sense.